# tagging sentence start <s> and end </s> with R for prediction

Tags: r, model, nlp, prediction

I'm building an NLP model to predict the next word in R.
So, for a 3 sentences corpus:

<.s> i like cheese <./s>

<.s> the dog like cat <./s>

<.s> the cat eat cheese <./s>

```
for a bigram model:
p(i|<.s>)= 1/3
p(the|<.s>)=2/3

p(like|i)=1/1

p(cheese|like)=1/2
p(cat|like)=1/2

p(cat|the)=1/2
p(dog|the)=1/2

p(like|dog)=1/1

P(<./s>||cat)=1/2
p(eat|cat)=1/2

p(cheese|eat)=1/1

p(<./s>|cheese)=2/2
```

so my model would predict:

```
    the (2/3) cat (1/2) eat (1/2) cheese (1/1) <./s> (2/2)
or  the (2/3) cat (1/2) </.s>
or  the (2/3) dog (1/2) like (1/1) cat(1/2) </.s> (1/2)
or  the (2/3) dog (1/2) like (1/1) cat (1/2) eat (1/2) cheese (1/1) <./s> (2/2)
or the (2/3) dog (1/2) like (1/1) cheese(1/2) <./s>
```

This is what I want, since it correctly assign me the probability of starting the sentence with "the" of 2/3

Sor far using `tm , I can make the unigrams and bigrams to calculate the probability, but to begin the sentence I would have to simply calculate which one is the most common Unigram

in my case:

```
like = 2/11
cheese = 2/11
the = 2/11
cat = 2/11
dog = 1/11
eat = 1/11
i = 1/11
```

Which would give me equal probability of beginning the sentence with "like", "cheese" , "cat" , or "the".

How can I introduce those sentence tags to get the accurate prediction for the word in the beginning of the sentence in R?

Comment: Isn't the probability of beginning the sentence with "cheese", "cat" or "like" zero since it didn't happen in your corpus while "the" is 2/3? I don't understand why want to start with the most common "unigram".

Comment: That's exactly my question. R doesn't know which word started the sentence unless I tell it so, i.e, tag the beginning of the sentence. Otherwise, to R, "the" and "cat" have the same probability of beginning the sentence